# Workaround for selecting template function implementation on MSVC++ 10.0

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

My purpose is to select different function implementation based on the memeber variable of data structure. I use member selection idiom "CREATE_MEMBER_DETECTOR" to detect if a data struct has certain member. In my case is to detect member base inside struct A_t and B_t (both of which has it) and member play_id inside base (A_t does not have play_id).The implementation below works on compiler MSVC++ 14.24. How can I make it work also on the old compiler MSVC++ 10.0, which yields tons of error on visual studio 2010. Some features in funtion template select_play_id are not supported   [image]

```
// templ_derive.h
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>

struct A_base_t {
    int id;
};
struct A_t {
    A_base_t base;

};

struct B_base_t {
    int play_id;
};
struct B_t {
    B_base_t base;
};

#define CREATE_MEMBER_DETECTOR(X)                                                   \
template<typename T> class Detect_##X {                                             \
    struct Fallback { int X; };                                                     \
    struct Derived : T, Fallback { };                                               \
                                                                                    \
    template<typename U, U> struct Check;                                           \
                                                                                    \
    typedef char ArrayOfOne[1];                                                     \
    typedef char ArrayOfTwo[2];                                                     \
                                                                                    \
    template<typename U> static ArrayOfOne & func(Check<int Fallback::*, &U::X> *); \
    template<typename U> static ArrayOfTwo & func(...);                             \
  public:                                                                           \
    typedef Detect_##X type;                                                        \
    enum { value = sizeof(func<Derived>(0)) == 2 };                                 \
};

CREATE_MEMBER_DETECTOR(base);
CREATE_MEMBER_DETECTOR(play_id);

template<typename T, bool>
struct use_base_s {
    static void valid(T data) {
        printf("bast t \n");
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct use_base_s <T, true> {

    static void valid(T data) {
        printf("no base t \n");
    }

    // U = T and decltype(U::base) do not work!
    template<typename U = T>
    static void select_play_id(U data,
        typename std::enable_if<Detect_play_id<decltype(U::base)>::value,
        std::nullptr_t>::type = nullptr) {
        printf("has player_id t \n");
        return;
    }
    template<typename U = T>
    static void select_play_id(U data,
        typename std::enable_if<!Detect_play_id<decltype(U::base)>::value,
        std::nullptr_t>::type = nullptr) {
        printf("no player_id t \n");
        return;
    }
};

// main.cpp
#include "templ_derive.h"
int main() {
    A_t a_o = A_t();
    B_t b_o = B_t();
    use_base_s<A_t, Detect_base<A_t>::value>::select_play_id(a_o);
    use_base_s<B_t, Detect_base<B_t>::value>::select_play_id(b_o);
}
```

really appreciate Any help!

Comment: Given that the code compile in VS 2019 (after adding `#include <cstdio>`), I would recommend you to upgrade to VS 2019 instead of trying to find workaround older compiler limitations.

Comment: @Phil1970 thank you for pointing out that errro. If  I could upgrade my compiler in project, I would not ask for help here.

Comment: Everyone knows that older Microsoft compiler are buggy when trying to write modern code. VS 2010 is older than C++ 11. The only other alternative would be to check if some libraries like boost and even then, you would probably have to get a much older version as probably most libraries requires at least C++11. Usually, it is not that hard to upgrade compiler and if you have part of you application that still require older compiler, it might be easier to split the application in two parts so that old code is isolated...

Comment: It is well know that the compiler was not very compliant and that newer standard have made many changes to make it easier to write advanced code. Compiler and langage have improved a lot in 10 years. Thus, either upgrade your compiler or invest moths in finding workarounds. I doubt you would get any help for Visual C++ 2010 while we would like that C++23 would already be available...